# Decoding base64 without extra allocations

Tags: go

I am trying to decode a very large base64 encoded string, possibly in the megabytes. I would like to base64 decode this string without allocating an output array of similar size. I would like to decode the string in place and re-use the underlying storage of the input string.

Is that possible?

Comment: *Strings* are read-only, so in that sense, no. If you store the input in a *byte array*, perhaps with a slice header, that's modifiable, so that way, yes.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you have a base64-encoded, immutable `string`? Converting from `[]byte` to `string` is wasteful. You should have a base64-encoded, mutable `[]byte`.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    enc := base64.StdEncoding

    // Test data
    b := make([]byte, 16)
    for i := range b {
        b[i] = byte(i)
    }
    fmt.Println(len(b), b)
    b64 := make([]byte, enc.EncodedLen(len(b)))
    enc.Encode(b64, b)

    // Decode base64 without extra array allocations
    fmt.Printf("%d %q\n", len(b64), b64)
    d := b64
    n, err := enc.Decode(d, b64)
    d = d[:n:n]
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(len(d), d)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/BfyaXjv_vwS

Output:

```
16 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15]
24 "AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODw=="
16 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15]
```

Note: Safe sharing of buffers can be implementation dependent. Write tests to ensure that it continues to be safe.

Comment: What does d[:n:n] do ? Never seen that.

Comment: @chmike: `slice[low:high:max]` - sets the capacity to `max-low`. See "Full slice expressions" in [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions)

Comment: @chmike: Full slice expressions: `a[low : high : max]` constructs a slice of the same type, and with the same length and elements as the simple slice expression `a[low : high]`. Additionally, it controls the resulting slice's capacity by setting it to `max - low`. [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)

Comment: @peterSO wouldn’t that imply to make a copy of the slice and thus an allocation ? Or will it only make a copy when low > 0 and max > cap(a) ?

Comment: @chmike you can't increase the capacity with the 3rd parameter to a reslice - so no there is no copying and no memory (re)allocation. And yes you are right, kostix's links are irrelevant to your question.

Comment: @chmike: `d = d[:n:n]`: There is no such implication. There is no copy. There is no allocation. `max > cap(a)` is invalid. See [Slice types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types) and [Slice expressions](https://golang.org) in [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec). Post a link to a Go Playground example which demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @peterSO if there is no copy, I assume there is also not a kind of ralloc taking place. What would then be the benefit in shrinking the capacity of the slice. Wouldn’t this simply make a lot of space inaccessible and wasting it ?

Comment: @chmike: `d = d[:n:n]` does not change the amount of wasted space. `d = d[:n:n]` safely hides the implementation algorithm -- with allocation or without allocation. `len(d)`, `cap(d)`, and array `d` are the same.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is possible using unsafe code.  As already suggested look for another alternative but ...

Maybe you're stuck because you're given a string (which you know is not in read-only memory) and you can't get access to a byte slice instead.  If you are careful you can modify a string something like this:

```
// build a string (string literals are kept in read-only memory)
sb := strings.Builder{}
sb.WriteString("abc")
s := sb.String()

b := *(*struct {p *[999999999]byte; length int})(unsafe.Pointer(&s))
// Be very careful not to write past the end of the string
b.p[b.length-1]++  // modify the last byte
```

Again, I can't stress enough that unsafe code is perilous, so you need to be very careful.  Eg make sure you don't write past the end of the string and understand why strings are immutable.

Comment: @peterSO sorry but his question was "Is that possible?".  I was just answering the question.